# Нужно ли здесь ставить запятую перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

В простейшем случае ИС вычисляется как линейная комбинация некоторых параметров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, здесь нет сравнения.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Это какое-то безумие, у коренных русских не должно быть подобных вопросов. А все из-за чего, из-за того что ложные программы навязаны, которые были придуманы и приняты без надлежащего рассмотрения. Запятые должны передавать точную конструкцию предложения передаваемую оппонентом. И подобных ограничений в расстановке запятых быть не должно.